# Is there a way to show the number of "ticks" or "steps" in a jquery ui slider?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I want to show the number of ticks in my jquery ui slider, is there a way to do this?

For example I have a slider with a max of 100, I want it some what like this

```
0--------50--------100
```

minus the dashes of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way, in my mind, is to put this above/below the slider:

```
<div id="slider_steps"> <span>0</span> <span>50</span> <span>100</span> </div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Then style the labels appropriately. You could also insert the labels into the `#slider` itself, but this will probably force the slider to be thicker for readability:

```
<div id="slider"> <span id="step">50</span> </div>
div#slider span#step {position:relative; left:50%;}
```

Comment: Ah yeah I had this in mind, but I was aiming for possibly a jquery ui slider option that is easily turned on and off such as like `Labels:true` or something along those lines.

Comment: That was my first thought; but the implementation is probably not worth the trouble.